# Add text to end of every line

Tags: text-processing, sed, osx

I have tried a lot of commands, like this:

```
sed -i '' "s/$/<@string>/" txt.txt > txt2.txt
```

This makes txt2.txt empty, why?!?

```
sed 's/$/<@string>/' txt.txt > txt2.txt
```

This does absolutely nothing and tells me that the path `<string>` doesn't exist.

So what do i do, I'm using bsd sed because I'm on OS X.

Comment: `-i ''` is for in-place editing. `txt.txt` has been modified. `sed` has produced no output.

Answer (score 3):

The `-i` switch causes `sed` to edit the original file. That means there is no output and since there is no output, your redirection results in an empty file.

So, what you want is either

```
sed -i '' 's/$/<@string>/' txt.txt
```

which will change the original `txt.txt`. Or, just

```
 sed 's/$/<@string>/' txt.txt > txt2.txt
```

Comment: It makes no difference, are you sure that its for bsd and not GNU? It give me no error but the file isn't changed.

Comment: @SurveySon the syntax is different for BSD (the `-i` needs a value which you are giving it with `''`) but the function is the same. If it's still not working, you probably have something strange in the input file or in whatever you are actually using instead of `<@string>`.

Answer (score 0):

The option `-i` in `sed` isn't quite compatible between Linux and Unix and it may not be available on other operating systems.

Secondly you can't use `-i` and IO-redirection (`>`) together, because it's excludes it-self. Using in-place editing already modifying the file.

So if you'd like to edit file in-place (into the same file), it's better to use [`ex`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor)):

```
ex +"%s/$/<@string>/g" -cwq foo.txt
```

To replace string and write to another file, try:

```
ex +"%s/$/<@string>/g" +"w another.txt" -cq! foo.txt
```

The command `ex` is equivalent to `vi -e`.

Comment: I solved this a year ago hehe, the problem was that the file was copied from an older computer with permissions problems.

Comment: @DisplayName I'm glad you solved it, but since then your question generated almost 1k views, therefore I wanted to share alternative solution using `ex`/`vi` which is quite interesting, especially for cross-compatible scripting purposes.

Comment: Yeah, yeah that's good, was just saying.